# Startup failure- snapd.service

Tags: kubuntu

I recently started using Ubuntu. This is a start-up error I came across just a day after the installation. The error message shows:

```
failed to start snapd.service-snap daemon.
```

The system gets struck in this error and never progresses further. Kindly let me know how to fix this. This is happening in startup and I don't have access to the terminal during this point.

[image]